# Objective c Image Loading from server view issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am loading the images from server using SDWEBIMAGE library downloaded from github.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

This is the view to my prototype cell.

[image: Prototypecell]

Image width and height is set to static and View-> Mode -> Scale to Fill.

Now when i load images from server it does layout issues, image is not placed properly in image container and not even scale to fill, Overlapping every thing tried to find a solution but nothing work's:

[image: Layout issue]

Another Screenshot

[image: Layout issue 2]

Tried allot to solve the issue but nothing found, if possible the image should resize it self but not to change the layout constrain's.

Here is my code:

```
 [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:urlimage placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"service-1.png"]];
    [cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i believe constraints are not set properly

Comment: y dont u set constraints to it ?

Comment: Looks like adding constraints to all the elements will fix your issue. Use the 'Add missing constraints' option in the storyboard, if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: @Vijayts all constrain's are set properly...

Comment: @Mr.T constrain's are set properly...

Comment: When i set an image manually every thing work's perfectly, but it happen's when the images load's from url

Comment: Solved problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are loading the image async, constraints will be set before image is ready, therefore it will use the UIImageView's edges for constraints. But because of content mode UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, edges are not matching with image size at the run time until the download is complete. You can make loading sync but it's not a good practice since it will block the UI. You have to come up with different workaround.

You can post a notification when image loading is completed and set the constraints with received notification. Therefore view will use latest layout constraints.